# Provide file download webpage without server side code

Tags: php, javascript, html, http

Lets say i have this string "something1,something2" and i want to download it as "text.csv", without opening new window (pop up) how could i do this from a webpage. can i dot it in JS without using this:

```
 window.open('data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + str);
```

or do i have to use PHP for this ?

Comment: What does "without a popup" mean? Why do you want to do this specifically?

Comment: If i used the Data Uri it will open new window to the user and its not good user experience to open new windows without really the need for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is a bit unconventional, but it is possible.

Take a look at [Downloadify](https://github.com/dcneiner/downloadify). It's a JavaScript library that leans on Flash to create a file on the client side and present the file download dialog.

David Walsh has some good demos and info too [on his blog](http://davidwalsh.name/downloadify).

Comment: Thanks but I rather a solution without requiring additional plug-in for the user to install (Like flash).

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you won't be able to do this due to browser sandbox/security concerns. Leaning on Flash or the server is the way to get out of that sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

While limited, there is also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Uri

So this as a url would open an image

> data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==

You could have javascript open this url to trigger the download

A CSV example

> data:text/csv,field1%2Cfield2%0Afoo%2Cbar%0Agoo%2Cgai%0A

Just copy/paste either of those into your browser to see them work.  Browser support is limited.

IE 8 for example has a 32KiB limit

Comment: IE will not download a file from a DATA URI.